# How to update uploaded file and delete the old one in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to edit the other stuffs in Edit mode but I don't want to re-upload the image file in edit mode which is already uploaded in create mode. So I want to view the path of the image in edit mode.

```
public ActionResult Edit(HttpPostedFileBase file, FileUpload fileupload)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string fil = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Files/"), fil);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    fileupload.FileURL = "/Content/Uploads/Files/" + file.FileName;
                }

                db.Entry(fileupload).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(fileupload);
        }
```

And Edit View Mode is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "FileUploadTest", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/Form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

      <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width:50%" />       

     <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

}

I have already uploaded the file using Create Action/View Method.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I use `Image` as a separate object to the main `Model` in question. So for instance a News article may have an image. When I edit (or add) I check to see if an image has been uploaded and **append** the image as a related object in the database. In this case, maybe you could have a `hidden` field with the image page and rename your `file` input to something non-model related to check at the point of submission. That way, if no image has been uploaded the hidden field will be used and the existing file path persists.

Comment: What's your `FileUpload` model? Is that is what you're want to change without reupload image?

Comment: @teovankot I am using simple model to hold the path of image.                                                             public class FileUpload
    {
        public int FileUploadId { get; set; }   
        public string FileURL { get; set; }
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be simply achieved by checking if file is not `null`, if it's not `null` we first get the previous file path and than after inserting and uploading the new one, we delete the previous file, and if file is `null`, we don't do anything and just edit other stuff, something like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit(HttpPostedFileBase file, FileUpload fileupload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          var model = _db.FileUploads.Find(fileupload.FileUploadId);
          string oldfilePath = model.FileURL;
            if (file!= null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Files/"), fileName );
                file.SaveAs(path);
                model.FileURL = "/Content/Uploads/Files/" + file.FileName;
                string fullPath = Request.MapPath("~" + oldfilePath);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                }
            }

            model.OtherStuff = NewStuff;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(fileupload);
    }
```

now if the `file` doesn't contain anything in edit mode, we don't have a problem because we don't upload anything, but if it has a value, we upload a new file and delete the old file, also you can show your current file in edit mode for your user.

Comment: Your code is not clear. It contains one local entityName but you have used this with db.Entry(entityName).State = EntityState.Modified;  I think it should be like this db.Entry(fileupload).State = EntityState.Modified;      I

Comment: @userKG I know, it's just a general example since I didn't know what are the real names, you can change it to suit your specific need with specific name, does it solve your problem?

Comment: I am still trying to fix the issue but can't. Please post some tested code.

Comment: I've updated the answer with what you gave us in your question and comments, if you need more help update your question with your FileUpload Model class and more detail, but I think hopefully you can do it easily with tinkering and changing this answer.